# Why is the two-way binding in this function not working in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, this

I am trying to change vm.info when it is coming back from an API call (using an outside library) and then display this in my view. But for some reason this is not updating my view and I can't use functions bound on my controller inside the function  `vm.session.service("ALMemory").done(function (ALMemory)`

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('cogController',
  function () {
        var vm = this;

        vm.testFunc = function() {
          alert('test');
        }
        // Get a response from API call
        vm.session.service("ALMemory").done(function (ALMemory) {
          ALMemory.subscriber("getJSON").done(function (subscriber) {
            subscriber.signal.connect(function (msg) {
              // msg is a Json file (is defined when logging it here)
              vm.info = msg;
              // logging vm.info gives the json file
              vm.testFunc(); // This function is not called
            });
        });
  });
});
```

Now my vm.info is not updated in my view.

View:

```
<body ng-app="cogApp">
 <div class="container" ng-controller="cogController as vm">
  <p>{{vm.info}}</p>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does vm.seesion.service offer an error callback? Maybe you've got an error there, which causes the ALMemory.subscriber to never get executed.

Comment: Try to set any dummy `string` in `vm.info` and see if that is you can see in the view or not

Comment: It might be that service call is failed. The rest of the code is working fine [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/OhbQ2NZinZlVznFArZ7d).

Answer (score 0):

call `$scope.$apply()` after setting vm.info

Comment: That won't we necessary, since vm is bound to the scope by using the as keyword on controller itself.

Comment: he is doing that using an outside library

Comment: The variable vm.info itself is updated in the controller and not in the foreign library.

Comment: ```ALMemory.subscriber("getJSON").done```

looks like an external library to me which has been provided a callback function which is a closure with reference to vm, hence it is updated outside angular

Comment: ```subscriber.signal.connect``` or maybe this one is external

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your services are injected and working as expected.

Here is an example setting the `response.data.body` value to `vm.info` and works fine:

```js
angular
  .module('cogApp', [])
  .controller('cogController', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var vm = this;
    
   $http
    .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(function(response) {
      vm.info = response.data.body;
    });
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="cogApp">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="cogController as vm">
    <p>{{vm.info}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```